# Does JMeter measure server response using junit sampler?

Tags: selenium, jmeter, junit4, load-testing

I want to integrate some functional tests to the performance tests using JMeter. And if I use JUnit sampler and run tests with starting the browser and execute some actions in the browser(clicks, entering text), what I will get in the JMeter listener: response time including browser speed OR only time of server response without browser execution?

What I do in JMeter: 
When I add JUnit sampler and open exported jar file of my test, and run it - test executes like usual web-driver test with browser start and loading UI elements, entering text and clicks. Will loading elements affect the time of the response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMeter will measure the time of the **whole test case**. If it assumes initialisation, launching browser, etc. - it will all be counted of course including the time required for the page to load / elements to render.

If you need to split your test into lesser chunks - consider migrating to [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/), if you choose [`groovy` as the scripting language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) you will be able to re-use your existing Java code and have better control over what's going on, add [sub-results](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#addSubResult-org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult-) for logical actions, group separate actions together using the [Transaction Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) and execute tests in parallel.